# How can I remove product thumbnail?

Tags: magento-1.7

How to remove the thumbnail images below the main product image on the product page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can remove from below file

```
app\design\frontend\default\default\template\catalog\product\view\media.phtml
```

code :

```
<?php if (count($this->getGalleryImages()) > 0): ?>
<div class="more-views">
    <h2><?php echo $this->__('More Views') ?></h2>
    <ul>
    <?php foreach ($this->getGalleryImages() as $_image): ?>
        <li>
            <a href="#" onclick="popWin('<?php echo $this->getGalleryUrl($_image) ?>', 'gallery', 'width=300,height=300,left=0,top=0,location=no,status=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes'); return false;" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_image->getLabel()) ?>"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'thumbnail', $_image->getFile())->resize(56); ?>" width="56" height="56" alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_image->getLabel()) ?>" /></a>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

make sure you are adding changes in your custom theme.

Comment: Actually I have a XML file which gives me facility to remove. For example I removed upsell by entering product.info.upsell. What is the similar key/handle for product thumbnail

Comment: A xml tag of template file is also content main image if you will remove from tag with `product.info.media` main image will also removed

Comment: @Haya,if my answer is useful please accept and useful answer should be reward

Comment: hi, what is the xml tag for "sign up for price alert", "add to wish list" and "share"